# Do i need to install ffmpeg-php to use ffmpeg?

Tags: php, html, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I am looking at coding a site to upload, convert and play videos. I  can code php. I want to use ffmpeg on my server. My question is, do i need to install and use ffmpeg-php when using ffmpeg? Thanks.

Comment: No, you can use exec() to call execute ffmpeg from the command line

Answer (score 0):

The FFmpeg PHP extension is only required if you want a native PHP API for doing FFmpeg work.  It is entirely possible to execute the `ffmpeg binary directly like you would any other.

I recommend using `proc_open()` to execute a child process and get its output from all streams.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php

Comment: ok tks I will get reading, so I can use standard php to upload a video file and convert it to other video types etc I can already do this ok but not the ffmpeg conversion

Comment: There is no native FFmpeg PHP extension. The classic "ffmpeg-php" is a dead, third party product. There may be other, more recent versions with the same or similar name too.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Good to know, thanks!  The last time I used it was ~10 years ago... I haven't kept on it.  I always just execute FFmpeg directly, for flexibility.

Comment: Yeah, understandably the way it's named seems to cause some confusion (same goes for a particular FFmpeg fork and its already-being-used name choices).